# Can Html Agility Pack be used to parse HTML fragments?

Tags: c#, .net, html, parsing, html-agility-pack

I need to get `LINK` and `META` elements from ASP.NET pages, user controls and master pages, grab their contents and then write back updated values to these files in a utility I'm working on.

I could try using regular expressions to grab just these elements but there are several issues with that approach:

- I expect many of the input files to contain broken HTML (missing / out-of-sequence elements, etc.)
- `SCRIPT` elements that contain comments and/or VBScript/JavaScript that looks like valid elements, etc.
- I need to be able to special-case IE conditional comments and `META` and `LINK` elements inside IE conditional comments
- Not to mention how HTML is not a regular language

I did some research for HTML parsers in .NET and many SO posts and blogs recommend the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex). I've never used it before and I don't know if it can parse broken HTML and HTML fragments. (For example, imagine a user control that only contains a `HEAD` element with some content in it - no `HTML` or `BODY`.) I know I could read the documentation but it'd save me quite a bit of time if someone could advise. (Most SO posts involve parsing full HTML pages.)

Comment: When you ask about parsing fragments, do you mean specifically in accordance with the requirements here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-end.html#parsing-html-fragments ? So HAP would have to be able to take a context node as an input?

Comment: @Alohci When I say fragment, I mean a piece of string that contains some HTML content. What that content is is completely unknown ahead of time - it could be valid XHTML or it could be nothing more than  `<bod></div></body>`. I'm really only looking for `HEAD` and then `LINK` and `META` so I don't really care about other content in the input but I'd like to avoid writing a parser for that since `SCRIPT` is hard to handle correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely, that is what it excels at.

In fact, many web pages you'll find in the wild could be described as HTML fragments, due to missing `<html>` tags, or improperly closed tags.

The HtmlAgilityPack simulates what the browser has to do - try to make sense from what is sometimes a jumble of mismatched tags. An imperfect science, but HtmlAgilgityPack does it very well.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to Html Agility Pack is [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery), a C# jQuery port of which I am the primary author. It lets you use CSS selectors and the full Query API to access and manipulate the DOM, which for many people is easier than XPATH. Additionally, it's HTML parser is designed specifically with a variety of purposes in mind and there are several options for parsing HTML: as a full document (missing `html, body` tags will be added, and any orphaned content moved inside the body); as a content block (meaning - it won't be wrapped as a full document, but optional tags such as `tbody` that are still mandatory in the DOM are added automatically, same as browsers do), and as a true fragment where no tags are created (e.g. in case you're just working with building blocks).

See [creating a new DOM](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery#creating-a-new-dom) for details.

Additionally, CsQuery's HTML parser has been designed to honor the HTML5 spec for optional closing tags. For example, closing `p` tags are optional, but there are specific rules that determine when the block should be closed. In order to produce the same DOM that a browser does, the parser needs to implement the same rules. CsQuery does this to provide a high degree of compatibility with browser DOM for a given source.

Using CsQuery is very straightforward, e.g.

```
CQ docFromString = CQ.Create(htmlString); 
CQ docFromWeb = CQ.CreateFromUrl(someUrl);

// there are other methods for asynchronous web gets, creating from files, streams, etc.

// css selector: the indexer [] is like jQuery $(..)

CQ lastCellInFirstRow = docFromString["table tr:first-child td:last-child"];

// Text() is a jQuery method returning text contents of selection 

string textOfCell = lastCellInFirstRow.Text();
```

Finally CsQuery indexes documents on class, id, attribute, and tag - making selectors extremely fast compared to Html Agility Pack.

Comment: Thank you - your library looks very good - unfortunately it's only for .NET 4.0 and I can't use it. My project has to support .NET 2.0 (not even 3.5 can be used for various reasons). I tried recompiling your project from the source in VS 2008 but the Concurrent namespace makes it pretty much impossible to do so. Do you, by any chance, have a 2.0 port of it?

Comment: Oh yeah - that would be a problem. It also uses Linq and dynamic types extensively, so backporting it to .NET 2.0 would involve major retooling. Sorry. (It could probably be redone without `Concurrent` collections - but you need at least 3.5 for dynamic & linq)

Comment: I really hope you'll consider someday to port your library over to 2.0. I understand the amount of work you'd have to do (I saw the number of errors when I tried compiling it), but your library seems quite a bit more reliable from the looks of it than HAP.

Comment: @xxbbcc - if your need is primarily HTML parsing and you can live without the CSS engine part of this, I literally just finished integrating a new HTML parser which will definitely compile under .NET 2.0. It is a port of the Mozilla/Gecko parser and so it's HTML5 compliant and fantastic at dealing with bad HTML (that is, it should give you the same DOM that Firefox does). The repo is here: https://github.com/jamietre/HtmlParserSharp and it includes a really basic demo to build an XML node tree. Since HAP uses the System.XML nodes too, it should be simple to swap this into HAP as its parser.

Comment: I may have to marry you, thank you! :) I'll take a look - I need a parser that can parse .NET code files (.aspx, .ascx, .master) which contain a combination of (possibly broken) HTML and HTML fragments and ASP.NET control definitions. I only need a handful of elements from the input but I need some of the most complex ones. I could write a parser myself but it's not a trivial task and it'd cost more than my project allows.

Comment: Hmm - i am not sure how it would do with aspx/etc files - but worth a shot. One problem you may have is using HTML5 parsing rules self-closing tags are considered unclosed, e.g. HTML5 simply doesn't recognize the self-close XML syntax like `<self-closing />`; it only recognizes that some tags don't need to be closed like `input`. Since aspx server tags are often self-closing i think this would be a prob. Html Agility Pack I believe has a little-known module that is designed specifically for parsing aspx files. I am sure I remember seeing this somewhere once... you might look into that, too.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. I know about the module in HAP but it hasn't been maintained for a long time based on what I've read. I may end up moving the project to .NET 4.0 if this becomes a serious problem and use your library. Thanks for your help again.